# How to use an Addon with ChartJS on Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, chart.js

I'm trying to use PieceLabel addon to show the labels inside the graphics but it's not working. The graphic is showing ok, here's my code:

**TS**

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js'
import * as ChartPiece from 'chart.piecelabel.js'

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.canvas2 = document.getElementById('myChartPie');
  this.ctx2 = this.canvas2.getContext('2d');
  let myChartPie = new Chart(this.ctx2, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Score',
            data: [11,21,31,41],
            backgroundColor: [
                'red',
                'blue',
                'orange',
                'green'
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
            responsive: false,
      display:true,
      pieceLabel: {
    mode: 'value'
  }
    }
  });
}
```

I installed both Chart.js and Chart.piecelabel.js with npm install --save. I tried to add this into the .angular-cli.json file but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/chart.piecelabel.js/build/Chart.PieceLabel.min.js"
      ]
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myChartPie" width="650px"></canvas>
```

It looks like my PieceLabel.min.js is not being called/recognized and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because, **`Chart.PieceLabel.js`** plugin doesn't have any exported member (neither *named* nor *default*). It just registers itself into the Chart.js plugin-service.

So, your **`import`** statement should be :

```
import 'chart.piecelabel.js';
```

instead of :

```
import * as ChartPiece from 'chart.piecelabel.js'
```

***sidenote:*** *you don't need to include this plugin script in `angular-cli.json`*

Answer (score 0):

delete import "chart.piecelabel.js", from component and add it in app.module.ts after the ng2-charts like this:

```
import { ChartsModule } from "ng2-charts";
import "chart.piecelabel.js";
```